# How to add list and delete list in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a grocery app where the shopper will add the list from the combobox, and the selection will be stored in the grocery.csv, and if the shopper needs to be removed the items from the list, he or she needs to uncheck the checkbox and the grocery.csv will remove the selected items accordingly.

```
check_box_list = []
def add_list():    
    f =  open('grocery.csv', 'a', newline='')       
    writer = csv.writer(f)        
    data = my_combo.get()       
    writer.writerows(data)
    f.close()

    var = StringVar()
    my_checkbutton = tb.Checkbutton(grocery_list, text=my_combo.get(), 
                                variable=var,  bootstyle="danger",
                                onvalue=my_combo.get())
    my_checkbutton.pack(pady=10)

    my_combo.current(0)

    check_box_list.append(my_checkbutton)

    my_checkbutton.var = var

def remove_list():   
    for i in check_box_list:
       if i.winfo_exists():
           i.destroy()
    
    check_box_list.remove(i)

    f =  open('grocery.csv', 'w+', newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(i)
    f.close()
```

I have the following issues:

1. When I add an item, for example, bananas, to the grocery.csv, however, it stores each letter in one row
   b
   a
   n
   a
   n
   a
   s
   instead of one row of bananas?
2. When I remove lists, all list items are deleted instead of those checked items
3. How do I update the lists after deletion, into the grocery.csv?